# "The court sentences the accused 5 years for his committing the crime." - what is "5 years" and "committing"?

Tags: parsing

I have a question.

> The court sentences the accused 5 years for his committing the crime.

Is it  in this sentence the structure is right. Subject (the court) , sentence is the verb, the accused is object.

Now, what about 5 years, is it noun?

What about for committing.......

Can the verb in the sentence be in the past?

Answer (score 2):

Idiomatically you should have

> ... sentences the accused **to** five years for ....

"years" is a noun, and the object of the preposition "to", forming a prepositional phrase with the numeral "five".  "Five years" is an idiomatic shortening, meaning "a time in prison lasting five years".

Similarly "for committing..." is a prepositional phrase. It includes an -ing form of a verb (participle/gerund)

In the example, the verb is in the present tense. This is the "commentary" present tense. It is used for describing actions that take place as they are described (like a sports commentator describing a game). The verb could be in the past tense, if you were describing past actions. It is a regular verb.

> Yesterday, the court sentenced the accused to five years.

Answer (score 0):

*Sentence* here works like *give*, and you can in fact substitute *give* and not change the meaning too much.

> The court sentences the accused 5 years for committing the crime
>
> The court gives the accused 5 years for committing the crime

I'm mentioning *give* because *give* is a word that takes 2 objects, a direct and indirect one.  Many other verbs when the meaning is similar or related to *give* also take 2 objects, and this is what "sentences" is doing.

So *5 years* is the indirect object (what is being given/sentenced) and *the accused* is the direct object (the target of the giving/sentencing).

Comment: We usually say 'sentence _to_ 5 years'.

Comment: Thanks, what about for committing the crime? Is it object also? Can the sentence be in the past?